# Controller or application service making HTTP Requests

Tags: design, clean-code

I'm in the school of thought of 'thin controllers', and love to push logic down into services and the domain models. However, I'm wondering if my controller should be making an HTTP Request to another web service or if the application service should do it. It seems that with my school of thinking then "yes" I should push it into the application service. However, this means the application service is stuck with HTTP only. So if I want to use a different communication protocol I'll need to implement another service like `RabbitMQService` instead of `HttpService`.

For example:

```
public Controller {
    // POST api/controller 
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task PostAsync([FromBody] Dictionary<string, int> data)
    {
        // get data from input json
        var output = service.doWork();
        // prep output data for outgoing HTTP Request

        // this here or in a service like 'HttpService'?
        await _sender.PostAsync(host + "/api/xxxxx", data);
    }
}
```

Or have the application service send the `PostAsync` request?

Comment: it would be helpful if you fleshed out your example with some details on what exactly the functions are supposed to do

Comment: @Ewan, I know the example is very abstract but I've added [slightly] more to it. Unfortunately, I cannot post the exact code. I do appreciate your answer below!

Comment: what I really need is the name of the function that you are calling on the httpservice. it doesn thave to be the real name. you can see im forced to use "DoWorkAndNextStep" it should be SendEmail or SaveContact or whatever

Comment: I use `ElectionService` to retrieve a `Election` by Id like `electionService.GetElection(electionId)`. And then use `Election` to vote for a candidate with `election.Vote(candidateId);`. After the vote is recorded, I make another HTTP request to the candidates. This is not very RESTful and not the way I'd ever design/develop an application. But it's a demonstration in making API calls between web services.

Comment: [Controller](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html). In a nutshell, controllers are requests handlers and forwarders. It's logic ideally is something like `handler > map > forwarding to business layer`. The dumber they are, the better

Comment: @Laiv, that I understand. Based on what you said: `controllers are requests' handlers and forwarders`; are you implying that the controller handles the communication?

Comment: No. Only handles the incomming requests to your system, not the calls/handling to the externals. That's someonelse problem.

Comment: @Laiv, boom got it now. That's what I had thought and it felt most natural, just wanted to check. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm your Controller doesn't seem very 'thin' to me. I would have

```cs
public Controller {

    private IElectionService service; //possibly sends over http or Rabbit or whatever

    // POST api/controller 
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task Vote(string electionId, string candidateId)
    {
        await service.Vote(electionId, candidateId);
    }
}
```

We can imagine that the ElectionService has various injected services

```cs
public class ElectionService : IElectionService
{
    private IElectionRepository repo; //calls election api
    public async Task Vote(string electionId, string candidateId)
    {
        var election = repo.GetElection(electionId);
        if(election.Candidates.Includes(candidateId))
        {
            repo.AddVote(new Vote(electionId, candidateId));
        }
        else
        {
            throw an exception!
        }
    }
}


public ElectionRepository_Http : IElectionRepository  {...}
public ElectionRepository_RabbitMQ : IElectionRepository  {...}

etc
```

Comment: This is exactly how I feel that it should be done.

Comment: updated with your names

Comment: So the repository should be dealing with communication?? Or do you mean something like `HttpElectionService : IElectionService`?

Comment: you could do it all in the service I suppose. I just naturally separated it out

Comment: `So the repository should be dealing with communication` repository should deal with data sources. Whether they are connections or access to the file system is irrelevant to the `ElectionService`. That's the point of the repository abstraction